# SFTP Error: "client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe"

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

I'm running an SFTP server using CentOS 8, I have a folder in `/var/` called "sftp" that is owned by Root and is assigned 777 permissions. Each user gets their own folder within `/var/sftp/` and has ownership of that folder i.e. user test1 gets a folder named `/var/sftp/test1/` and owns that folder.

I would like it so that when a user logs into th server their root would be their folder. Here is the configuration in my sshd_config file that I'm using to try and achive that:

```
Match User test1
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/test1
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

When I try and login to the user I get this error:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

But when I set the ChrootDirectory to "/var/sftp" I don't get that error, but the "sftp" folder is their root instead of their folder.

Comment: The folder /var/sftp must be writable only to user root. So it cannot be 777, since others may write into this folder. Ownership should be root:root.